# Equal Area SRID for Finland?

Tags: coordinate-system, srid, finland

Does anyone know the SRID for an equal area projection that is suitable for Finland?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [ESRI:102013](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102013/) it is the Europe Equal Albers Area. Kind of like the USGS albers projection but for Europe.
I would be concerned than Finland is on the geographic fringes and actually into the polar regions and this is better suited for mid-latitude Europe.

An non-ESRI definition appears to exist. [EPSG:3035](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3035/).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  However, note that ESRI:102013 and EPSG:3035 are actually different - the former is the Albers Equal Area as you point out, but the latter is the Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area.  Will go with EPSG:3035.

Comment: You are correct. I made it sound like they are two version of the same thing but one is albers and one in Lambert. I agree go with 3035.